# Evaluating an indefinite integral by "completion of cube" method

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral involving a cubic polynomial in the denominator of the integrand:
$$\int\frac{r^ndr}{r^3+ar^2+br+c}$$
Solving this integral in Mathematica gives the result

[image]

Here, one can observe that the integral is expressed as a sum of three terms corresponding to the three roots of the cubic polynomial. However, I tried to solve the integral analytically by "***completion of cube***" similar to the completion of squares method, but I was unsuccessful.

My question is whether such an approach could be used to solve the integral? I could not find any resources regarding "completion of cube" method. Also, if the approach is not a suitable one, are there any other method to solve such an integral?

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{r^n}{r^3+ar^2+br+c} \,dr=\int\frac{r^n}{(r-r_1)(r-r_2)(r-r_3)}\,dr$$
Now, using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{r^n}{(r-r_1)(r-r_2)(r-r_3)}=a_1\frac {r^n}{r-r_1}+a_2\frac {r^n}{r-r_2}+a_3\frac {r^n}{r-r_3}$$ making that you face integrals
$$I=\int \frac {r^n}{r-k}\,dr=-\frac{r^{n+1}}{k (n+1)} \, _2F_1\left(1,n+1;n+2;\frac{r}{k}\right)$$

Comment: Among the three roots $r_1, r_2, r_3$, two of them are complex. I had obtained the integrand as a part of a 'force' which I need to integrate to obtain the corresponding potential. So how should the complex values be interpreted in the expression for the potential of a physical system?

Comment: @Richard. If $(a,b,c)$ are real numbers, the end result will be real. I agree that the simplification will not be the most pleasant task.

Comment: It's important to note that this answer only covers the case where the $r_i$'s are all distinct. Multiple roots have to be taken care of in a separate case. (although you can perturb the function very slightly to ``separate'' the roots)

Comment: @b00nheT. Thanks for pointing this !